# Widgets missing after update

Tags: widgets

After doing an update to 4.7, all widgets are missing. I queried the database for any records wp_options like '%widgets%' and all is the same as the backup. What can cause this or how can the widgets be restored?

Comment: Try searching `wp_options` for option name like "widget" (singular): `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%widget%' `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to restore sidear_widgets in wp_options and any other entries with option_name including 'widget' from a database backup to resolve. Something must have go wrong during the update and all widget settings were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your update probably went wrong.

Start again from the update page, or upload the missing/incomplete files by ftp.

If you want to verify manually, you will find the related files in `wp-includes` folder `widgets.php` and widgets folder with classes for core widgets.

Hope it works after.

Comment: You mean try the 'Reinstall Now' button on the update page?

Comment: Yes, "reinstall now" button, or check manually before but it could be long

Comment: Same after reinstall :( It seems only widgets are missing, would those types of things be affected by files?

Comment: Did you try to enable debug mode to see if some of your widget works with the last version. Some plugin throw warning about the method that is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Next step would be to look at your PHP error log and see if there are any clues in there. You may have an incompatibility issue.  Make sure all plugins are up to date as well.